# Laravel Nova管理パネルのテキストフィールドで「JSON UNESCAPED UNICODE」が機能しないのはなぜですか？

Tags: php, laravel

私は、[Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/)を使用した開発を進めております。
直面した問題とは、データベースに保存する際の日本語が文字化けする問題になります。

以下、私の開発環境になります。

- Laravel 7.14.1
- Nova 3.6.0
- PHP 7.3.11
- MySQL 5.7.22
- Amazon Linux release 2
- Chrome 81.0.4044.138

問題が発生するまでのシナリオは以下になります。

1. データベースの作成 (照合順序  :UTF8mb4 Unicode)
2. モデルとマイグレーションファイルの作成 (テーブル名は「Area」とします。)

```
php artisan make:model Area --migration
```

3. 「area」のマイグレーションファイルに、4列 (id, name, created_at, updated_at)を追加し、マイグレートします。
4. Novaの管理画面で使用するモデルリソースを定義します。

```
php artisan nova:resource Area
```

5. Novaのモデルリソースファイルに以下のスクリプトを追加して修正します。

```
public function fields(Request $request){
　　return [
　　　ID::make()->sortable(),
　　　Text::make('Name')
　　　　->sortable()
　　　　->rules('required', 'max:24')
　　];
}
```

6. Novaの管理画面のインプットフォームから日本語のデータを挿入します。今回はデータとして「北海道」を記述します。[image: 管理画面より日本語を入力]
7. 「Areaを作成」をクリック後、保存されたデータを確認すると文字化けてしまいました。 [image: 保存されたデータが文字化け]

以上が、私の直面している問題になります。

参考になる記事をいくつか見つけることができました。例えば「[Laravel 5 Model $cats to array utf-8 JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241424/laravel-5-model-cats-to-array-utf-8-json-unescaped-unicode)」です。こちらの記事では、対象のModelに「asJson」 関数を上書きするという記事でしたが、まったく動きませんでした。

他のサイトで掲載されていた記事「[Laravelのjson応答でユニコードのエスケープをやめさせる](https://qiita.com/crhg/items/efbbac09bc4df838f984)」は、とても有効な記事かと実践してみましたが動かず、ミドルウェアを作成して解決する「[[Laravel] JSONレスポンスのUnicodeエスケープ無効化はミドルウェアで！](https://nextat.co.jp/staff/archives/203)」を実践してもダメでした。

問題の解決は、インプットフォームでPOSTされた日本語を、データベースに保存する際に、Jsonに書き換えられるときのエスケープを止めることにあるような気がしています。ただし、私がLaravelとNovaをまだ理解しきれていない故に、どのファイル、どの関数を修正したら解決できるのかが、今一歩進めていない状況です。

現在、Laravel Novaを導入されている方で、日本語を使用している環境を構築されているか
方、このような問題をすでに解決されている方がおりましたら、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。
原因は、php.iniの設定項目「mbstring.encoding_translation」によるものでした。
初期設定では、「On」になっていますが、「Off」にすることで、文字化けを解決することができました。
JSONの文字化けというより、Formアクションでの文字化けでした。

たわいもないミスで恥ずかしいばかりですが、ここに記します。